# Mockito mock does not work as expected in Spring MockMvc test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito, spring-test-mvc

In an *Spring* *mockmvc* test I want to replace a bean by a mock implementation which is configured using `Mockito.when()` definitions. The definitions are indeed respected at the time the mock is configured, as well as at the time the mock is injected into a depending bean (a controller advice in my case) during application context startup. However, when the mock is used during a certain test, all `when` definitions are gone.

Why?

Some remarks:

- The mock is completely new code, so it is impossible that I am not aware of any call to `Mockito.reset()`.
- the mock at the time of usage is the same as at the time of creation.
- a bypassing solution to the problem is to configure the mock in a `@BeforeEach` method in `AbstractTest`. However, I want to understand why it does not work without.

Here a simplified and anonymized example

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    private String property;

    ...

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice() {

    private MyBean myBean;

    @Autowired
    public MyControllerAdvice(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
        System.out.println(this.myBean.getProperty()); // --> outputs "FOOBAR"
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public String getMyBeanProperty() {
        return myBean.getProperty(); // --> returns null
    }
}


public class AbstractTest {

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        public MyBean () {

            MyBean myBean = Mockito.mock(MyBean.class, "I am a mock of MyBean");
            when(myBean.getProperty()).thenReturn("FOOBAR");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add  your test.

Comment: Why not execute once using `@BeforeClass`?

Comment: @M.Deinum The test does not matter, it is just a spring integration test which starts the application context and does not make any usage of the mentioned beans.

@user7294900 : But even then, I do not understand why Mockito looses the `when()` definitions without being resetted.

Comment: The test does matter, as it shows you things are setup.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem of Mockito. I think you simplified the example a lot and we don't see the full picture, but I can say that main cause - 2 different beans MyBean: one is initialized with Spring's `@Component`, second is in configuration class with `@Bean`.

1. Why do you use `@Component` for POJO/DO?
2. `@Bean` in the configuration class is being initialized lazy so better way to use `@PostConstruct`
3. If you want to leave both beans mark `MyBean` in the configuration class as `@Primary`

Comment: No, there are not two beans of `MyBean`: the one configured with `when(..)` is the same as the one injected in the constructor and the same as the one referenced in `MyControllerAdvice::getMyBeanProperty()`. I checked this by means of debugging.

Regarding your three questions:

1. The non-simplified version is more than just a POJO
2. It's not true that @Bean is initialized lazy.
3. True, indeed, the actual code has `@Primary` although it is not necessary. In case, of concurring `@Bean` in a config class  and  `@Component` beans, the `@Bean` is chosen